# High Sierra Calendar app undocumented behaviour

Tags: calendar

To reproduce:

1) Create a new event

2) Type as the first line of the note the characters `message:`

Result:
the word `message:` converts to `Show in Mail...`

This happened to me by accident when I added this as the first line of a calendar note, and it deletes the rest of the text in the note if there is any.

First I wondered if this was a feature I didn't know about. I’m keen to learn more about calendar features, but it seems to be some undocumented behaviour or maybe a bug/accident.

Any thoughts to share on this?

Comment: I'm not incredibly familiar with either app, but I'm pretty sure this is part of some integration between the mail.app and the calendar.app. I don't know why it would autofill that though.

Comment: I am seeing this behavior on my machine. It looks like a bug to me. It also happens if you put it in the "Add URL" field, and then it actually creates a link that brings Mail.app to focus if you click on it. I'm guessing this allows you to go back to an email where an event was sourced when automatically generated.

Comment: You can drag&drop a mail message into an event to create a `message:` link back to Mail (which even works if you move the mail to another folder within Mail afterwards). Looks like a bug in Calendar though if it converts typed strings into a reference like this.